# How can I add more than one inline assembly instruction in a macro with VC++?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, compiler-construction, compiler-errors, inline-assembly

Why does the following macro compile with 1 inline assembly instruction but not with 2?

This code compiles OK:

```
#define foo(x,output,ctx) {\
    __asm\
    {\
        mov eax, 0xCAFEBEE1\
    }\
}
```

but this code produces an error:

```
#define foo(x,output,ctx) {\
    __asm\
    {\
        mov eax, 0xCAFEBEE1\
        add eax, 5\
    }\
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#define foo(x,output,ctx) {\
    __asm mov eax, 0xCAFEBEE1 \
    __asm add eax, 5\
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you have a problem with the pre-processor, be sure to use Project + Properties, C/C++, Preprocessor, Preprocess to a file = Yes.  Build and you'll find a .i file in the build directory.  Which shows this on your snippet:

```
int wmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    { __asm { mov eax, 0xCAFEBEE1 add eax, 5 }};
    return 0;
}
```

Now it is obvious, there are no line endings on the macro lines.  Curse at the preprocessor a bit to make you feel better.  Then one __asm per line to fix.